# Stop script execution under apache user

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos5, virtualhost

My vhost server's users are allowed to access only their directories, but today i was under attack someone uploaded files by user apache in folder `/tmp` and executed files.
How can i stop upload by user apache and prevent these type of execution?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> How can i stop upload by user apache

Use [open_basedir](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1616)

> prevent these type of execution?

Use safe_mode_exec_dir